# HTML responsive Mail Signature

Tags: responsive-design

Is it possible to do a mail signature in a responsive manner? I am doing responsive websites with media queries. Can I use media queries for mail signatures also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some emails clients support media queries, while others do not. As with everything concerning HTML emails, it's a crap shoot. See this page for a list of email clients that support media queries:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/

You can put the media queries in a `<style>` tag right after the `<body>` tag and the email clients that support media queries will recognize it. The best case, IMO, would be to code the signature with your normal set of media queries. I'd probably use as much of a fluid layout as possible for the signature, and use the media queries to change font-size, etc.

There's a ton of guides out there on how to do responsive HTML emails. I'd recommend reading through them for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use inline css for your email templates and inline css doesn't support media queries.

Answer (score -1):

inline css does support media query.. just add an !important; for all your css inside medias, like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.mobile {width: 300px !important;}
.mobile-font {font-size: 14px !important;}
}
```